# How to assign specific field to a variable

Tags: powershell

I would like to assign `SamAccountName` to a variable while I run `Get-ADUser` cmdlet in PowerShell, I tried the following command but always return error.

```
$manager_sam = Get-ADUser -Identity $manager |fl SamAccountName
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Select-Object` instead of the `Format-List` cmdlet:

```
$manager_sam = Get-ADUser -Identity $manager | Select-Object -expand SamAccountName
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `$manager` contains a string that's valid to be passed as `-Identity`, you can just use

`$manager_sam = (Get-ADUser -Identity $manager).sAMAccountName`